# Android: always launch start activity when app is destroyed and recreated

Tags: android

Lets say I have two activity, A and B.
A - is my splash activity, and it also handles the initialization part. When i launch app, `Activity A` is started or launched and then it gets navigated to `Activity B`. Then i press `home button`, and wait for some time, for app to be destroyed. And i press my app's icon again, and my android (5.0) remebers what activity i stoped using, and launches it (activity B). and App crashes, since initialization was not occured. How to force android to start my activity A in any case?

I had also tried `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`

I had even tried to `finish()` activity if it is activity B, but anyway onCreate of fragments are called, and app crashes.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to kill the activity when you press homebutton. finish() the activity B in onpause() or onStop() method of the activity.

Comment: I do not want it to be killed! But if it is killed, than it should be started through activity A

Comment: yeah thats what exactly happens here.it will start from activity A once B is finish().

Comment: I should not kill activity B anyway. That is impossible anyway. If app is not killed, I want activity to be onStarted from activity B, in normal flow

Comment: can you show me the log of the error you receive when you resume your activity..

Comment: My activity's B fragments receive call of onCreateView, and there I need inited vals from activity A (internet connection, and lots lots of other staff)

Comment: First of all you can't just wait for app to be destroyed, the only sure way is to kill it from the task manager. On the other hand you are also saying that you do not want the activity to be killed. I suggest you to restate your problem and needs clearly in the question.

Comment: I do not need it to be killed. But if it is killed, all init work has to be done again, and I have to launch activity A.

Comment: then  you got one more way. Store all the values you are getting from A to sharedPreferences, and get all the values again from sharedpreference when you resume the activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call `finish();` on your `Activity B's` `onStop()` method. It could close your `Activity B` once the focus is off from the activity and now the app can start from `Activity A` again on relaunch.

May be this can help you...

Comment: I do not want it to be killed! But if it is killed by android system, than it should be started through activity A

Comment: @AntonKizema Could you write the code of your Activity B? And are you calling finish() on Activity A?

Comment: Please put the logcat error also if possible with your Question along with some code of Activity B if possible...

Comment: There should be general way of solving my auestion. The code will not give you any info. Crash I receive because activity A did not do init. and i do not want to do init in any other activity, there are lots of reasons

Comment: @AntonKizema Check for the Initilised values in your Activity B, and if those values are null, then start your Activity A from the onCreate() method of your Activity B. This could solve your issue. 
If you can provide the additional details some other way could also get to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely upon Activity `A` and `B` dependence. We do not have any control whether the OS decides to kill any of those. It might be due to battery limits or a need to free up memory.

This can be also checked with 'Dont keep Activities' developer option.

What I suggest doing is adding an if-check logic in Activity B to use the init config or init it, if not possible.

Then, you will be prepared for the case of Android killing your activity (rare case than `A` -> `B` flow, but possible).

Hence, Activity logic coupling is a no-go.